# setup pi3 to work with embedded modem through TXD RXD

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, modem

how can I configure pi3 (GPIO ) connected to embedded modem through (UART Pin 8-Pin 10)TXD RXD?  and how can write python code to control with modem?

Comment: You need to explain why what others have done does not work for you.

Comment: @Same Abazed, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. Typical hobbyist grade modems talk default 9k6BdN81. So now Rpi3B+/Rpi4B python sets up on board or USB serial also at 9600BdN81. Now Rpi Python sends a message "AT", and Modem should reply "OK". Some modems might need leading characters before "AT". Perhaps you can give me the link to your modem and somebody can check out for you. Cheers.

Comment: @joan this question is the first step in my project .

Comment: remote fax receive only 3kb from message , disconnected after 10 second from phase 3 beginning... I am using mt9234smi embedded modem